# Which D3 visualization/layout is suitable for Data Lineage?

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

As a newbie loving D3, I am trying to visualize data movement from source to destination that goes through multiple systems.  But I am having hard time identifying suitable layout.  Tried using Chord and Tree but don't know how to represent intermediate systems visually. Are there any recommendations/rule of thump on which layout/diagram is more appropriate for a given purpose (e.g.data lineage)?

Comment: Please forgive me if you already know this, but *layout* in D3 has a different meaning from layout in dataviz: in D3, "layouts take a set of input data, apply an algorithm or heuristic, and output the resulting positions/shapes" (API). Of course, it has to do with the visualization itself, but it's not the same. My advice is this: try to find the best visualization method for what you want, literally paper-to-pencil, and only then, after deciding the best method, think about the best D3 *layout* for that method. As I like to say: the technology has to suit your idea, not the contrary.

Comment: Meanwhile, have a look here for some tips: http://www.visual-literacy.org/periodic_table/periodic_table.html

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: Thanks. No, I didn't know the difference between those two.  I was framing the question with words known to me i.e. D3, Data Lineage, Diagram, Layout, Visualization etc.

Comment: @Bala Did you ever identify a viable solution to this question?  I'd love to implement something similar.

Comment: @CJTravis I ended up using Sankey which seem to be the closest available at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @Bala.  Do you happen to have a code snippet that illustrates how you fed the Sankey to produce the lineage diagram?